# IllegalStateException not caught

Tags: java, scala, javafx-2, javafx-8, uncaught-exception

i want to catch an IllegalStateException in Scala. Following code

```
val scene = new SceneDock
```

throws an IllegalStateException if an JavaFX-Application was not started before. This constructor is from the JemmyFX framework.

So i want to catch this Exception in the following way:

```
try{
 val scene = new SceneDock
 "running"}
catch{
 case e: IllegalStateException => { "stopped" } }
```

But it doesn't work. The output is always the IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized  and it repeates until i terminate the application. Have already tried to catch Exception, and tried it with Java, but always the same result.

stack trace (it repeads until i terminate the app):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:155)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:150)
at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:52)
at org.jemmy.fx.QueueExecutor.executeQueue(QueueExecutor.java:98)
at org.jemmy.action.AbstractExecutor.execute(AbstractExecutor.java:100)
at org.jemmy.fx.SceneList.getControls(SceneList.java:58)
at org.jemmy.lookup.PlainLookup.getChildren(PlainLookup.java:76)
at org.jemmy.lookup.AbstractLookup.refresh(AbstractLookup.java:172)
at org.jemmy.lookup.AbstractLookup$1.reached(AbstractLookup.java:141)
at org.jemmy.lookup.AbstractLookup$1.reached(AbstractLookup.java:137)
at org.jemmy.timing.Waiter.waitState(Waiter.java:78)
at org.jemmy.timing.Waiter.ensureState(Waiter.java:119)
at org.jemmy.lookup.AbstractLookup.wait(AbstractLookup.java:137)
at org.jemmy.lookup.AbstractLookup.get(AbstractLookup.java:250)
at org.jemmy.lookup.AbstractLookup.wrap(AbstractLookup.java:210)
at org.jemmy.dock.Dock.lookup(Dock.java:75)
at org.jemmy.fx.SceneDock.<init>(SceneDock.java:20)
at org.jemmy.fx.SceneDock.<init>(SceneDock.java:32)
at org.jemmy.fx.SceneDock.<init>(SceneDock.java:60)
at org.djemmysl.main.DjemmySL$class.applicationStatus(DjemmySL.scala:25)
at org.djemmysl.main.Main$.applicationStatus(Main.scala:3)
at org.djemmysl.main.Main$.main(Main.scala:6)
at org.djemmysl.main.Main.main(Main.scala)

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:155)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:150)
at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:52)
at org.jemmy.fx.QueueExecutor.executeQueue(QueueExecutor.java:98)
at org.jemmy.action.AbstractExecutor.execute(AbstractExecutor.java:100)
at org.jemmy.fx.SceneList.getControls(SceneList.java:58)
at org.jemmy.lookup.PlainLookup.getChildren(PlainLookup.java:76)
at org.jemmy.lookup.AbstractLookup.refresh(AbstractLookup.java:172)
at org.jemmy.lookup.AbstractLookup$1.reached(AbstractLookup.java:141)
at org.jemmy.lookup.AbstractLookup$1.reached(AbstractLookup.java:137)
at org.jemmy.timing.Waiter.waitState(Waiter.java:78)
at org.jemmy.timing.Waiter.ensureState(Waiter.java:119)
at org.jemmy.lookup.AbstractLookup.wait(AbstractLookup.java:137)
at org.jemmy.lookup.AbstractLookup.get(AbstractLookup.java:250)
at org.jemmy.lookup.AbstractLookup.wrap(AbstractLookup.java:210)
at org.jemmy.dock.Dock.lookup(Dock.java:75)
at org.jemmy.fx.SceneDock.<init>(SceneDock.java:20)
at org.jemmy.fx.SceneDock.<init>(SceneDock.java:32)
at org.jemmy.fx.SceneDock.<init>(SceneDock.java:60)
at org.djemmysl.main.DjemmySL$class.applicationStatus(DjemmySL.scala:25)
at org.djemmysl.main.Main$.applicationStatus(Main.scala:3)
at org.djemmysl.main.Main$.main(Main.scala:6)
at org.djemmysl.main.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

Comment: Could there be two IllegalStateException classes? (I hope not)

Comment: No, the output says it is the java.lang.IllegalStateException, so i dont think there is another one ;)

Comment: Can you add the stack trace to the question?

Comment: In that case can you try `case e: java.lang.IllegalStateException => { "stopped" } `

Comment: I have tried this as well, but no other result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instantiation `SceneDock` wait a little (10 sec by default, i guess) until a `jemmy fx` application is launched. 
During this wait, it lookups periodically (each 100ms by default) if a window have been opened by executing a task in the javafx `thread` (using `Platform.runLater(Runnable)`).

Invoking `Platform.runLater(Runnable)` when no application have been launched, a `java.lang.IllegalStateException`is thrown, caught and print to the error output:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:153)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:148)
    ...
```

If no application have been done after a while, you should get a `org.jemmy.TimeoutExpiredException`:

```
org.jemmy.TimeoutExpiredException: State 'Waiting for 1 javafx.scene.Scene controls to be found adhering to org.jemmy.lookup.Any@65e7c41f' has not been reached in 10000 milliseconds
at org.jemmy.timing.Waiter.ensureState(Waiter.java:121)
at org.jemmy.lookup.AbstractLookup.wait(AbstractLookup.java:138)
    ...
```

I get this behavior with the following code :

```
import org.jemmy.TimeoutExpiredException;
import org.jemmy.fx.SceneDock;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestX {

    @Test
    public void notInitializedToolkit() {
        try {
            new SceneDock();

        } catch (TimeoutExpiredException e) {
            System.err.println("The application have not been launched");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so you mean because it is catched before, i can not catch it after the output? Do you have another method to test, if the Application is running or not?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no public API to get the running application. You could use `Window.impl_getWindows()` to get the all the opened windows.

Comment: I think i have found the solution: Simply i use the method that throws the IllegalStateException. in the try block i call Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                def run() {
                }
            }); Now i can catch the Exception.